# HighStock | Page crashing when panning

Tags: crash, highcharts, freeze, panning

first of all, I'd like to point out that I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557414/highstock-zooming-on-xaxis-causes-browser-crash) SO Question and, sadly, it didn't solve my problem.

My issue is as follows:
I need to display charts with, sometimes, up to 5 times 100 000 points and for that I decided to use HighStock (it is not my only reason, but let's not get off topic already).

Everything works fine except for one *(not so little)* detail: if I try to click and drag on the chart with my mouse (for zooming or **panning**), the whole **page crashes**, or at least stops responding for 30+ seconds. And that is weird because I don't face this problem if I zoom/'pan' using the timeline below the chart.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/DixiPoowa/Lsurmuow/5/) is a JSFiddle showing what I mean (comment the line 40 in order to reproduce the issue).

```
chart: {
    /* panning: false */
}
```

Because of that, I also tried using HighCharts and [there](https://jsfiddle.net/DixiPoowa/r7c1f04b/4/) I have no issue (other than the graph not looking as good... but that's because I almost didn't configure anything).

After doing some testing, I noticed that disabling the panning solves my problem.

```
chart: {
    panning: false
}
```

But then, the only way to move/zoom the chart is by using the timeline which, even if it is not that big of a deal, can be annoying when using a phone (if you go in landscape mode in order to see more of the chart, because my website isn't just displaying a chart alone, it becomes kinda impractical).

**tl;dr:**

- I have the solution but I'd like to know if it's a know issue, the solution, the reason for that behavior.
- Should I mark my question as "I answer my own question" ?, in the end I'm still not sure why it it happening, all I know is a fix

Comment: "Hi, " or "Hello is removed from my question Oo ?

Comment: I removed all the unnecessary parts from your code: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yrkry3dr/ and changed the `zoomType` value to `x` (`null` is not a valid value according to the API:  https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.zoomType). Zooming is quite fast, but panning takes a lot of time. Both operations are in general changing the extremes of the chart so there's something wrong with panning. It seems like a bug to me. You can report it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I notice that, on your code, I am able to zoom from the start without crashing.
But just like in mine panning causes a crash, but only when dragging directly the graph. 
I think I'll report it just like you suggested ^^

Comment: And after testing, I see that the reason why yours isn't crashing is because your panKey is "ctrl" while mine is "shift" (just like in their demos) and that's causing the issue.

Comment: Wait no, it's something else, probably my imports causing a conflict because i don't get a crash when I try to zoom and have "shift" set as panKey on your example. I'll still post an issue cause I'm curious

Comment: Ok I feel dumb... Because I was setting `zoomType` to `null`, my click and drag would cause panning right away. Now, this doesn't explain why panning by clicking on the graph would cause a crash but not when using the timeline.